# Xamarin.Forms detect Custom ContentView click outside event

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a **CustomCalendar** element created by extending the **ContentView** and using this custom view inside another **ContentPage**. I tried to use **Unfocused** event to detect the outside click. But the problem is it is not triggering the event handler. Could you please suggest me to do the detecting of an element outside click in a better way.

I am using my custom view like this way in the page with an Unfocused EventToCommandBehavior

```
<views:CustomCalendar x:Name="cal">
       <views:Calendar.Behaviors>
             <prism:EventToCommandBehavior 
                           EventName="Unfocused"
                           Command="{Binding UnfocusedCalandar}"/>
       </views:Calendar.Behaviors>
</views:Calendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unfocused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.unfocused?view=xamarin-forms) event is raised whenever the VisualElement loses focus, and it only works for the element which is able to receive focus , unfortunately ContentView  can't receive focus , so `focused` and `Unfocused` event would never trigger on ContentView .

Elements that can receive focus : **Entry , Editor , Picker, and so on ..**.

---

As a temporary workaround , you could wrap the ContentView into StackLayout, set tap gesture both on ContentView  and parenet layout , its own tap gesture will block parent view's gesture .

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" >
        <ContentView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" >
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ContentViewTap"/>
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>


        <CollectionView BackgroundColor="Gray" Focused="CollectionView_Focused" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="dog.png"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding }"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding }"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />

                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StackLayoutTap" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Grid>


                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>


        </CollectionView>

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StackLayoutTap" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this way but it is triggering only when exactly the stack layout tapped. When we click other elements within the stack layout it is not triggering.

Comment: `StackLayoutTap`  triggers when we click on all the elments within stack layout , it works fine on my side .

Comment: In my XAML there is a CollectionView inside the StackLayout so when I click any item inside the CollectionView it is not triggering.

Comment: Add Tap gesture on the element inside `CollectionView.ItemTemplate` , and assign the event to `StackLayoutTap ` ,Check my update .

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach but the problem here is if there is a different type of layouts we need to add that tap gesture to all those layouts.

Comment: For instance , ListView has item tap event, we need to invoke `StackLayoutTap ` method manually when click on that controls which can receive focus or block tap gesture .

Comment: Hi , if my answer helps could you mark it as answer. or you could post your solution here and mark it .